# Delegates with methods that have different number of parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

I've run into a problem. I have something like that:

```
public class ListSorter : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    public static MyDelegate myDelegate;    
    void Start () 
    {
        ListSorter.myDelegate += A(5);// <-- here I know i cant do it
        ListSorter.myDelegate += B;    
        myDelegate(); //<-- how to call 2 different function with one delegate?
    }
    public void A(int iVar)
    {
        print(iVar);
    }    
    public void B()
    {
        ///...
    }
}
```

So as you see, I already know where and how many of parameters I want to have. The question is how to call those function A and B while function A has a parameter and B doesn't have one?

Comment: See aslo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: @JonHanna Currying is not the solution to this problem, and as the method that he has only has one parameter, it is *already* curried.

Comment: @Servy no the solution is partial application, going from a 1-parameter method to a 0-parameter method. The page linked to covers it as well as currying and uncurrying.

Comment: @JonHanna Yes, the solution is *partial application*, not currying, so why not link to the article on partial application, rather than the article on currying?

Comment: @Servy because I ended up there looking for Partial Application, and my eye skipped past "Main article: Partial application" pointing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application which is indeed the better article, so I thought it was just covered under that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the function call in an anonymous delegate that matches the target type (no parameters, no return value):

```
ListSorter.myDelegate += (() => A(5));
ListSorter.myDelegate += B;
```

Comment: Omg! That was so easy. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

To call `A` with a fixed parameter you need to create a new method that matches the delegate's signature, namely having no parameters and no return value, who's body calls `A`, passing `5`.  You could do this with a new named method, or you could use an anonymous method; both would work fine:

```
ListSorter.myDelegate += () => A(5);
```

Other than that, you're properly creating a delegate that calls two methods, so invoking it will invoke both of the method's you've added to it.